# Using a mask/transparent pixel/alpha for template matching in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to simply apply a mask to locate a template, which is simply a square, on my screen with OpenCvs match template function. The goal is to locate the box, and ignore the contents inside of it.

the template looks like:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB4e5.png)

My approach was to simply binarize and invert this template, and use that as a mask to feed into matchTemplate(), however I keep running into errors which are hard to interpret.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

template = cv2.imread(path + 'tile_outline_pink.png')
image = cv2.imread(path + 'test_screenshot.png')

w, h = template.shape[:-1]
#data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)



templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv2.imwrite("imghatGray.png", imghatGray)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(templateGray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#cv2.imwrite("orig_mask.png", orig_mask)

mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
#mask_inv = cv2.cvtColor(mask_inv,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

print(image.shape, image.dtype)
print(template.shape, template.dtype)
print(mask_inv.shape, mask_inv.dtype)

method = cv2.TM_SQDIFF 

result = cv2.matchTemplate(template, image, method, None, mask=mask_inv)
```

the output is as follows:

(674, 969, 3) uint8
(41, 45, 3) uint8
(41, 45) uint8

---

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     31 method = cv2.TM_SQDIFF
     32 
---> 33 result = cv2.matchTemplate(template, image, method, None, mask=mask_inv)
     34 
     35

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:235: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'cv::setSize'

I have also tried to convert the template image into an RGBA image but that hasn't worked either, I am not really sure how to proceed

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I realized a made a really stupid mistake,

I inadvertently switched the image, and template arguments in matchTemplate()

as well, the mask and the template both need to be RGB, or the exact same dimensions.

So, for those wanting a simple example for template matching with a mask, this code works for me:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

template = cv2.imread(path + 'tile_outline_pink.png')
image = cv2.imread(path + 'test_screenshot.png')

w, h = template.shape[:-1]

templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(templateGray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
mask_inv = cv2.cvtColor(mask_inv,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

print(image.shape, image.dtype)
print(template.shape, template.dtype)
print(mask_inv.shape, mask_inv.dtype)

method = cv2.TM_SQDIFF 

result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, method, None, mask=mask_inv)
```